# SQL / SQLite Query that counts the number of text occurrences based on date

Tags: sql, sqlite

Below I have an example of a query that I am trying to perform. The INPUT is the table that I have access to. The OUTPUT is how I would like to organize the data. I am trying to group the data by the date and have an output for the number ups and the number of downs, so the output will give a string, int, int.

This query is a little more advanced than I've done before, but I think I will need something similar to this:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*), COUNT(*) FROM Input GROUP BY date
```

I am not sure how to format the COUNTs to look for only UP or DOWN on a particular date. Could someone help point me in the right direction

**INPUT**

| date | time | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 12:12:12 | UP |
| 2022-01-01 | 13:12:12 | DOWN |
| 2022-01-01 | 14:12:12 | UP |
| 2022-02-04 | 12:12:12 | UP |
| 2022-02-04 | 13:12:12 | DOWN |
| 2022-02-04 | 14:12:12 | DOWN |
| 2022-03-05 | 12:12:12 | UP |
| 2022-03-05 | 13:12:12 | UP |
| 2022-03-05 | 14:12:12 | DOWN |

**OUTPUT**

| date | # of UP | # of DOWN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-02-04 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-03-05 | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `sum` with a conditional case expression

```
select date, 
  Sum(case when status='Up' then 1 else 0 end) NumUps, 
  Sum(case when status='Down' then 1 else 0 end) NumDowns
from t
group by date;
```

Comment: Your answer seems to work, I just have one more question. Right now it is tallying correctly, but when there are 0 found it returns a NULL. Is it possible to return a 0 if none are found?

Comment: In which case it just needs and `else` I have amended.

Comment: Thank-you so much for your answer. Also found the following to work as well:

`select date, 

  IFNULL(Sum(case when status='Up' then 1 end),0) NumUps, 

  IFNULL(Sum(case when status='Down' then 1 end),0) NumDowns

from t

group by date;`

Comment: Yes that's essentially the same, but the single case expression is better and avoids the need for another function.